# How to create filterable portfolio in WordPress?

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, javascript

I'm creating a Portfolio custom page in WordPress, so far I've been able to get the categories from the custom taxonomy.

Now what I want is when clicking on an option, it should fetch the post with the custom category.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-small btn-default" data-toggle="portfilter" data-target="all">All</button>
                <?php 
                    $terms = get_terms("portfolio_categories"); // Consigue todas las categorias del custom taxonomy.
                    $termsString .=  $term->slug;
                    $count = count($terms); //Cuantos categorias son?
                    if ( $count > 0 ){  //Si es que hay mas de uno
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //Para cada termino:
                            echo "<button class='btn btn-small btn-primary' data-toggle='portfilter' data-target='".$term->slug."'>".$term->name."</button>\n";
                        }
                    } 
                ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="row">
        <?php $portfolio_query = new WP_Query(array(
          'post_type' => 'portfolios',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          ));
        $terms_portfolio = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_categories');
        ?>     
        <?php if($portfolio_query->have_posts()) : while($portfolio_query->have_posts()) : $portfolio_query->the_post();  ?>
        <div class="col-md-4" data-tag="<?php echo $terms_portfolio[0]->slug; ?>">
            <div class="thumbnail">
            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-page'); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="caption">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php  else : ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger text-center"><p>Ningun portfolio encontrado</p></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Can somebody check my code? I'm unable to show the category in the `data-tag` od the `div col-md-4`

This the current status:

[image]

The output of this in the source code is the following:

```
<div class="col-md-4" data-tag=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `$terms_portfolio` too early. You're using `get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_categories')`, but `get_the_ID()` won't be the current portfolio in the loop because `$portfolio_query->the_post()` hasn't run yet.

Change this bit:

```
<?php $portfolio_query = new WP_Query(array(
          'post_type' => 'portfolios',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          ));
        $terms_portfolio = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_categories');
        ?>     
        <?php if($portfolio_query->have_posts()) : while($portfolio_query->have_posts()) : $portfolio_query->the_post();  ?>
        <div class="col-md-4" data-tag="<?php echo $terms_portfolio[0]->slug; ?>">
```

To:

```
<?php 
$portfolio_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolios',
    'order' => 'DESC',
));

if($portfolio_query->have_posts()) : 
    while($portfolio_query->have_posts()) : $portfolio_query->the_post();  
        $terms_portfolio = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_categories'); 
        ?>

        <div class="col-md-4" data-tag="<?php echo $terms_portfolio[0]->slug; ?>">
```

Comment: Oh my God, it works!!!. I've been trying to solve this the whole day lol . I just did not know how to make it happen!! :/. Thank you sir!!